# JavaScript event sequence

Tags: javascript, events, sequence, timing

Some events in JavaScript fire before others. For example, with an input element, the keydown and keypress events fire first. Then, if the return value from those was not false, the input.value is updated. Then, the keyup event fires.

Is there a web site where I can find a comprehensive list of all events and the order in which they are executed, as well as other things that take place in between, such as updating the value in the input box in my example?

Such a list would be extremely helpful.

Comment: And yes... I've looked on google.

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282245/what-is-the-event-precedence-in-javascript

Answer (score 5):

For key events, the following is an excellent resource: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html. There's also a page for mouse events on the same site at http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html that I haven't used, but I imagine is useful based on the key events page.

Comment: This looks like what the asker wants to me.

Answer (score 2):

I know a good german web site, also available in French I hope this helps:

http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/sprache/eventhandler.htm

Comment: I did take a year of German in High School, but I'm afraid it's a bit too rusty (that was 10 years ago). No french either. +1 for your effort tho

Comment: please try to keep your posts to english. http://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/1235.php might have the information you need, but it's in spanish, so it probably won't help. :D

Answer (score 0):

[W3C - Document Object Model Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-eventgroupings) - but as always... some browsers doesn't support everything.