# Precedence of the JavaScript events

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Is there any precedence to the JavaScript events that occur in a HTML page?
For example:

Consider these two events `onchange` and `onblur`.

Change the text of a text box. The event `onchange` occurs only `onblur` of the text box.
In this case which event will be processed first.

I hope I gave the understandable example.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282245/what-is-the-event-precedence-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested it on firefox and the onChange event occurs before the onBlur, but the onChange is fired only when you really change the input value. Anyway there is always a certain order in events occurance.

Answer (score 0):

onChange, occurs first, if this is what you are asking