# What's the first event fired when a web page is loaded to the browser

Tags: javascript, dom-events

As asked in the title, what's the first event fired when a web page is loaded to the browser? I believe there are events before `window.onload`. What are they, and which one is the first fired?

Comment: Is this a trivia question, do you generally want to run some code before `onload`, or do you want to run some code at some specific point before `onload`?

Comment: similar question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282245/what-is-the-event-precedence-in-javascript

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking to invoke an event handler before `onload`, `DOMContentLoaded` is one event that usually fires before.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', functionRef, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps but firebug/IE Dev Tool is really good for watching JS events execute as the page loads. I use that to caputre events and see the order of how they're happening.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to have some of what you're looking for:

[Updated link - link-rot - this is why you copy and paste essential information directly into an answer]

https://web.archive.org/web/20090131201912/http://dean.edwards.name:80/weblog/2005/02/order-of-events/