# Clear focused field with a special "reset" button

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to take a button and make it to a reset button for one field in multiple field form.

```
<button id ="resetbutton" type="button">reset focused field</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById('resetbutton').onclick= function() {
        // Get the focused element:
        var $focused = $(':focus');
        var field= document.getElementById($focused);
        field.value= "";
    };
</script>
```

the focused field variable doesn't work for me and it doesn't get the focused field that I need to reset, any suggestions?

maybe when I press the button I get a focus on the button but what I really want is latest focused field.

Comment: *What doesn't work? Be more specific.*

Comment: Presumably because the field loses focus when you click the button.

Comment: yes you are right, I saw in this answer that there is no way to get the previously focused element from javascript, any workaround to that?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329141/how-do-i-get-the-previously-focused-element-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you retrieve the focused element by a click on a button, the element in question will always lose the focus just before that. To get the ID of a previously focused element you should track the focused elements. Create a `last_focused` variable that holds the ID for the last focused element, and update it when ever one of your form elements gets the focus. Then, when you click on your `resetbutton`, just use this value to handle the element.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Lawrence's answer, this is how you might implement it:

```js
var previouslyFocused;

$("input").on("blur", function(){
    previouslyFocused = this.id;
});

$("button").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#" + previouslyFocused).val("");
});
```

```css
input{
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
    <input type="text" id="age" placeholder="Age" />
    <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Address" />
    <input type="text" id="shoeSize" placeholder="Shoe size" />
    <button>Reset focused field</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution for that is to use html5 type input "search" that adds a small "X" beside that input so you can reset it individually.