# How do I keep an input focused even when I click a button outside it

Tags: javascript, input, focus, onblur

Let's say I have an input

```
<input type="text" id="inPut" autofocus>
```

and a button

```
<button id="btn">Some text</button>
```

I want that onblur, it loses focus (as it normally would), but when I click this button, nothing happens to the focus i.e it does not lose focus

Comment: If the button is clicked when the input does not have focus should the input gain focus?

Comment: @BenStephens No it should not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### You can use JS to focus the input on button click.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
const inp = document.querySelector("#inp");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  inp.focus();
});
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="text">
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

#### If you don't want the input to focus on click if it is not already focused.

To achieve this we cannot simply do:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (inp === document.activeElement) {
    inp.focus();
  }
});
```

Because the condition `inp === document.activeElement` would never be true, as clicking on the button would make the button the active element.

We can use the `mouseover` event and store the input's
focus" information in a variable and this would not suffer from the same problem as before because `mouseover` would fire before the button gets focused.

And then inside the `click` listener we will focus the input if it was already focused.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
const inp = document.querySelector("#inp");

let isInputFocused = false;

btn.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  if (inp === document.activeElement) {
    isInputFocused = true;
  } else {
    isInputFocused = false;
  }
});

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (isInputFocused) {
    inp.focus()
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="text">
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: @EmekaOrji Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: I was thinking that this second example wouldn't work on my phone because I wasn't expecting the mouseover event to fire just from a click, but it appears to work for me. If anyone finds that this doesn't work on a touch device, then possibly mousedown or pointerdown (or both) events could be used instead of mouseover (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329141/how-do-i-get-the-previously-focused-element-in-javascript ).

Comment: Thanks @SomShekharMukherjee I will get back to you (here) as soon as I try it out

Comment: It was so helpful, I'm still trying to figure out how it worked, but it did!! Thanks @SomShekharMukherjee