# Jquery focus(in|out) run in weird order

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is that when there is a focus on one `#input1`, and i try to focus it on `#input2`
by running

```
$('#input2').focus();
```

first runs the `focusin` event of `#input2` then the `focusout` of the `#input1`

Why does this happen, why isn't `focusout` running first?

Please see for an example http://jsfiddle.net/zZZsD/3/
Type in first input 4 symbols

UPDATE: Btw, I've used delegated binding instead of direct for performance reasons,there will be potentially lots of input fields...

Comment: I don't see the problem. When I'm in #input1 and click on #input2, it says "focusout of input1, focusin of input2" so i don't know what you mean...

Comment: you should not click on #input2, click on #input1 and type 4 symbols in order to trigger focus()

Answer (score 1):

There's something called **Event Hierarchy**. It decides what order the events are fired in.

It's important to make a note of this if your case requires one to fire before another.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282245/what-is-the-event-precedence-in-javascript) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is a internal mechanism of jQuery, or even "worse", of Javascript Engine in the browser. If it's important the order, you can use the *blur* method before the *focus*.

```
(function () {
    $('#cont').on('keyup', 'input', function (event) {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val().length == 4) {
            input.blur();
            $('#input2').focus();
        }
    });

    $('#cont').on('focus', 'input', function () {
        $('#events').append('focusin of ' + this.id + ' <br>');
    });

    $('#cont').on('blur', 'input', function () {
        $('#events').append('focusout of ' + this.id + ' <br>');
    });

})();
```

Maybe the navigator check for focused elements when you select another element and unfocus them.