# Prevent firing the blur event if any one of its children receives focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, onblur

I have a [div](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Other_block_elements) on a page that shows some information about a particular category (*Image*, *Name*, etc).

When I click on the edit image, it puts the category into edit mode which allows me to update the name. As you can see from the image below, it shows that "Soup" is currently in edit mode, and the others are in normal view mode. This all works as expected with the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> / <kbd>Save</kbd> buttons doing everything right.  (I tried adding an image, but it wouldn't let me, and it needs more love.)

**However**, once in edit mode, if I click anywhere else on the page (Outside of the div), the expected result would be that the soup category would go back to view mode. Upon an event firing of some sort, this should also allow me to ask if they wanted to save changes.

So then I decided to create a blur event on the "soups" parent *div*. This works as expected if I click anywhere on the page. However, if I click on the inner element of the *div*, it also causes the parents blur event to be fired, thus causing the category to go back to view mode.

So, is there a way to prevent the parent *div* from firing the blur event if any one of its children receive focus?

```
<div tabindex="-1" onblur="alert('outer')">
    <input type="text" value="Soup" />
</div>
```

I just wrote the code without a compiler, so I am not sure if that even works, but with that, hopefully you get the idea.

I'm using Knockout.js to update the GUI on the fly, but that shouldn't affect this answer I wouldn't have thought.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I've had to tackle this problem before. I am not sure if it is the best solution, but it is what I ended up using.

Since the click event fires after the blur, there is no (cross-browser, reliable) way to tell what element is gaining focus.

Mousedown, however, fires before blur. This means that you can set some flag in the mousedown of your children elements, and interrogate that flag in the blur of your parent.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/L5Cts/

Note that you will also have to handle `keydown` (and check for tab/shift-tab) if you want to also catch blurs caused by the keyboard.

Comment: Sir, you are a gentleman and a scholar. I've been trying different solutions to this problem in different situations for over a year. Never realized the timing of all the events, thanks a million.

Comment: I've been trying to find some sort of official definition of event order/precedence to see if this can be relied on. This is an old question, but if the answer is still true this solution might work just due to coincidence: https://stackoverflow.com/a/282271/2382483. Id love to find a really solid solution to this, but everything seems to be a work around or hack.

Comment: This example, while for React, can be adapted for pretty well any use. It uses focus on the new element and blur on the original, and uses a timer to cancel the blur event when focus fires. https://medium.com/@jessebeach/dealing-with-focus-and-blur-in-a-composite-widget-in-react-90d3c3b49a9b

Comment: This may be a hack, but I use a setTimeout on the blur and a clearTimeout on the child click.

Answer (score 152):

I faced the same issue. This what worked for me.

```
 handleBlur(event) {
    // if the blur was because of outside focus
    // currentTarget is the parent element, relatedTarget is the clicked element
    if (!event.currentTarget.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
        .....
    }
}
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: With some editing, I got this to do what I wanted; Had to handle cases where relatedTarget === null. Still seems a more appropriate answer than using mousedown.

Comment: If you are running into typing issue with Typescript (`Argument of type 'EventTarget' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.`) you can write it is `currentTarget.contains(e.relatedTarget as Node)`

Comment: can someone add the full code for reference @yahel,@petermoore

Comment: If your related target is always null, you will need to add a focusable element to the target. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764494/blur-event-relatedtarget-returns-null

Comment: What's the difference with focusin/focusout above?

Answer (score 30):

I don't think there is any guarantee `mousedown` will happen before the focus events in all browsers, so a better way to handle this might be to use [`evt.relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget). For the `focusin` event, the `eventTarget` property is a reference to the element that is currently **losing** focus. You can check if that element is a descendant of the parent, and if its not, you know focus is entering the parent from the outside. For the `focusout` event, `relatedTarget` is a reference to the element that is currently **receiving** focus. Use the same logic to determine if focus is fully leaving the parent:

```
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');

parent.addEventListener('focusin', e => {
    const enteringParent = !parent.contains(e.relatedTarget);

    if (enteringParent) {
        // do things in response to focus on any child of the parent or the parent itself
    }
});

parent.addEventListener('focusout', e => {
    const leavingParent = !parent.contains(e.relatedTarget);

    if (leavingParent) {
        // do things in response to fully leaving the parent element and all of its children
    }
});
```

Comment: react doesn't allow the use of focusin or focusout :/

Comment: too bad, at least vuejs does

Comment: @WouldBeNerd The synthetic onBlur / onFocus events in React do bubble (like their native cousins focusout / fousin) and therefore you can just use those in React:
`<div onBlur={event => { if (!event.currentTarget.contains(event.relatedTarget)) doStuff(); }} />`
And btw you _can_ use native events in React; you just have to get a `ref` and call `addEventListener` (which can be wrapped inside a [hook](https://github.com/teetotum/react-panoply/blob/master/src/useEvent/index.js))