# blur event.relatedTarget returns null

Tags: javascript, events, onblur, lost-focus, focusout

I have an `<input type="text">` field and I need to clear it when this field loses focus (whiech means that user clicked somewhere on the page). But there is one exception. Input text field should't be cleared when user clicks on a specific element.

I tried to use `event.relatedTarget` to detect if user clicked not just somewhere but on my specific `<div>`.

However as you can see in snippet below, it simply doesn't work. `event.relatedTarget` is always returning `null`!

```js
function lose_focus(event) {
  if(event.relatedTarget === null) {
    document.getElementById('text-field').value = '';
  }
}
```

```css
.special {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 25px 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
.special:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="text-field" type="text" onblur="lose_focus(event)" placeholder="Type something...">

<div class="special">Clicking here should not cause clearing!</div>
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

**Short answer:** add `tabindex="0"` attribute to an element that should appear in `event.relatedTarget`.

**Explanation:** `event.relatedTarget` contains an element that *gained* focus. And the problem is that your *specific* div can't gain a focus because browser thinks that this element is not a button/field or some kind of a control element.

Here are the elements that can gain focus by default:

> - `<a>` elements with `href` attribute specified
> - `<link>` elements with `href` attribute specified
> - `<button>` elements
> - `<input>` elements that are not `hidden`
> - `<select>` elements
> - `<textarea>` elements
> - `<menuitem>` elements
> - elements with attribue `draggable`
> - `<audio>` and `<video>` elements with `controls` attribute specified

So `event.relatedTarget` will contain above elements when `onblur` happens. **All** other elements will are not counted and clicking on them will put `null` in `event.relatedTarget`.

But it is possible to change this behaviour. You can 'mark' DOM element as element that can gain focus with *[tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)* attribute. Here is what standart says:

> The `tabindex` content attribute allows authors to indicate that an element is supposed to be focusable, whether it is supposed to be reachable using sequential focus navigation and, optionally, to suggest where in the sequential focus navigation order the element appears.

So here is the corrected code snippet:

```js
function lose_focus(event) {
  if(event.relatedTarget === null) {
    document.getElementById('text-field').value = '';
  }
}
```

```css
.special {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 25px 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
.special:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="text-field" type="text" onblur="lose_focus(event)" placeholder="Type something...">

<div tabindex="0" class="special">Clicking here should not cause clearing!</div>
```

Comment: Note that on macOS/iOS in Safari/Firefox some form controls ([at least `<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Clicking_and_focus)) are not focused when clicking.

Comment: Setting it to 0 adds it to keyboard tab list, which might be undesirable. Use -1 instead to prevent that.

Comment: adding on to list of things that result in null relatedTarget (chrome): cross-origin iframe tabindex or not (maybe all iframe?), elements that lost focus because they were removed from dom

Comment: Note that if you don't want it to be focusable with keyboard navigation (for accessibility reasons), you should set `tabindex="-1"` instead of 0, and it's working as well.