# How to specify the order of a focusout and a click event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an input field with a JS `focusout` event. Under my input field, I have an autocomplete popup with suggestions. But when I click on a suggestion, it’s playing the focusout before the event listener on the click of the autocomplete! Any clues on how I can I fix this conflict?

Picture of the input and its autocompletion:

[image: Picture of the input and its autocompletion]

The `click` event:

```
resultsFrom.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let e;
    e = event.target.parentNode;
  inputFrom.value = e.getAttribute('data-display');
});
```

The `focusout` event:

```
inputFrom.addEventListener('focusout', () => {
  const list = document.querySelector('#results-from');
  let first = list.firstChild;
  inputFrom.value = first.getAttribute('data-display');
  resultsFrom.innerHTML = '';
});
```

Comment: try `event.stopPropagation()` in the `click` event. Or add some variable as flag (e.g. `var clicked = false`) and set it to true in `click` event and in `focusout` check if variable is true or false. And then set to false.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski That probably won't work, since the two are separate events. `stopPropagation()` stops the event from bubbling up the DOM tree

Comment: @MátéSafranka Yep, you're right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`focusout` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout) has a property on the event object of `relatedTarget` - this is the element that's going to gain the focus, in this case, it will be the element you're clicking on.

You need to check if that element is within your results, and not clear them out if that's the case.  Something like this:

```
inputFrom.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
  const list = document.querySelector('#results-from');
  if (!list.contains(e.relatedTarget)) {
    //the target is not in the list, continue as before
    //otherwise allow the click to function by not clearing out resultsFrom
    let first = list.firstChild;
    inputFrom.value = first.getAttribute('data-display');
    resultsFrom.innerHTML = '';
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to implement the relatedTarget but it doesn't work yet. When I put a console.log(e.relatedTarget); over the `if (!list.contains(e.relatedTarget)) {...}` it indicates null every time the focusout happens. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: I think perhaps you must be using an element that can't gain the focus - what do you use for your results?  Perhaps they need to be `<a>` tags so they can get the focus when clicked on.

Comment: They are `<li>...</li>`

Comment: Ok - check out [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42764495/791010) then - in addition to my answer above, you need to make it so the elements you're clicking on can gain focus.  Either by using an element that can receive focus by default, or that answer suggests that adding `tabindex="0"` to your `<li>`s should also work.

Comment: Thanks so much you're right. It works like a charm with tabindex="0".