# ionBlur Event: Detect the element that is receiving the focus

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

From a custom directive, I want to determine what is the element that is receiving the focus when a blur event occurs:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[my-directive]',
  host: {
    //...
    '(ionBlur)': 'onBlur($event)'
  }
})
export class MyCustomDirective implements OnInit {
    //...
    onBlur($event) {
        console.log(event) // This logs a CustomEvent that contains information only about the element that losing the focus
        console.log(event.relatedTarget) // This logs undefined
    }
    //...
}
```

I am using this directive with an `ion-input` element:

```
<ion-input my-directive></ion-input>
```

When testing, the `event` parameter of the `onBlur` method contains the attributes `target` and `currentTarget` which both are the element that is losing the focus, **but** the `event.relatedTarget` was undefined:

[image]

Is it possible to have the element that is receiving the focus too?

Comment: Maybe the `relatedTarget` property is what you are looking for (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33325953/1009922)).

Comment: Thanks for your proposition. Unfortunately the result of `event.relatedTarget` was undefined. I edited my question to mention it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic 5.3 finally [added this feature](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/17363).

You can now access the element which is gaining focus via `ionBlurEvent.detail.relatedTarget`.

Note that `ionBlurEvent.detail` contains the "original" HTML [`FocusEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent).

Note also that the [`FocusEvent.relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget) may still be null — in case that no "focusable" element receives focus. See also: [blur event.relatedTarget returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764494/blur-event-relatedtarget-returns-null)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need a Hostlistener to watch for blur events.
And when you catch blur event with a HostListener:

```
  @HostListener('ionBlur', ['$event'])
  onBlur($event: FocusEvent) {
    console.log(event)
  }
```

You can see relatedTarget is available

[image]
But

```
    console.log(event.relatedTaget)
```

will give a compiler error.

As it's a JSON structure, to get it, I suggest this:

```
console.log(event['relatedTarget'])
```

then you will get this:

[image]

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xgxawe)

Comment: I think that the `blur` event isn't taken into account as it is not fired when the element loses the focus. In my Ionic app, I need to use the `ionBlur` event, and as I mentioned in my question, the `$event` param is an instance of `CustomEvent` and the `relatedTarget` attribute does not even exist. I will edit my question to add a screen capture of the logged event

Comment: Thanks for the example. Unfortunately the `blur` event isn't fired when I am using an `ion-input` element instead of on `input` element. The only event that is fired when losing focus from an `ion-input` is `ionBlur`, and when using it, the `relatedTarget` attribute is undefined

Comment: Thank you again for the updated example :) I followed the same code in my app but it is still not working. The difference that I am noticing between your stackblitz example and my app, is that I am using the version 4.0.0 of ionic-angular, while the version used in the example is 3.9.2

Comment: Isn't the latest ionic-angular version 3.9.3 ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-angular

Comment: My bad, instead of ionic-angular, 4.0.0 is associated to @ionic/angular: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/angular

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187881/discussion-between-strider-and-vega).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ionic 4, and for me what worked best:

```
onFocusLostEvent() {
    let input = event['target'] as HTMLElement;
    console.log(input.id); // the id of the ion-input object for its identification
}
```