# Exclude some element to be part of the 'focusout' event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have input and div

```
    <input id="input" />
    <div id="div">Hello</div>
```

on this input i attached focus out event so whenever i click outside of the input - it gets triggered. That means also when i click on the div itself, the focus out event gets triggered.

```
let input = document.getElementById('input');
console.log(input);
input.addEventListener('focusout', () => {
    alert('focusout event happening');
})
```

but i need - when i click on this div - focus out event to not be triggered on the input itself.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

An event handler can accept an event as an object. Events do include the DOM node that they were triggered by as their `target` property - however in case of a [`FocusEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent) that is the element that lost focus, in that case your `input`. So this won't help. However `FocusEvent` does have an additional property called [`relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget). In case of a `focusout`-Event this includes the DOM node that received the focus.

Using this, you could do something along those lines:

```
input.addEventListener('focusout', e => {
    if (e.relatedTarget === document.getElementById("div")) {
        alert('FocusOut event triggered by div');
    } else {
        alert('FocusOut event triggered by other element');
    }
})
```

However a [focusout event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event) is not canceable, so you cannot  prevent the focus change from happening.

You CAN hoever re-focus the input right after the focus change by calling `document.getElementById("input").focus()`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But when i try your example - i get null in the e.relatedTarget. Why is that ?

Comment: It seems like there is no relatedTarget  property on the event object

Comment: Do you get null when you focused the div after the input, or in other cases?

Comment: If the first case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764494/blur-event-relatedtarget-returns-null/42764495#42764495