# React onBlur event currentTarget and relatedTarget are null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an MUI icon that makes a div (absolute positioned) appear. I want to "close" the div whenever the user clicks outside of it. I read some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component/44378829#44378829) and I'm trying to close the div using onBlur event. It works fine if I click outside of it however if I click in children elements of the div it closes too. I'm trying to use this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44378829/14451633) however the currentTarget and the relatedTarget are `null`. I added `tabIndex={0}` as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764494/blur-event-relatedtarget-returns-null) still not working though.

Here is the code:

```
const handleCogClick = () => {
 setShouldShowSettingsMenu(true);
};


<SettingsIcon
 sx={{ fontSize: "50px" }}
 tabIndex={10}
 onFocus={handleCogClick}
 onBlur={(event) => {
  console.log("event ", event);
  if (!event.currentTarget.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
   setShouldShowSettingsMenu(false);
  }
 }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it may be late  but this could help some people to resolve this.

Resolving the issue is made by propagating manually the currentTarget and relatedTarget values.

```js
  protected onBlurHandler(event?: React.FocusEvent) {
    const currentTarget = event.currentTarget
    const relatedTarget = event.relatedTarget
    this.setState({focused: false}, () => {
        // current and related are null here
        event.currentTarget = currentTarget
        event.relatedTarget = relatedTarget
        // Next handlers in flow will not have null values
        this.props.onBlur(event)
    })
  }
```

What you are seeing is the first method that catches the real element blurEvent (the one you should have in SettingsIcon). If you have access to this component, you can adapt, if not, I dont know how you can resolve it