# onBlur is called from child elements

Tags: reactjs, onblur

i have a container div that contains many inputs and checkboxes inside, i want to trigger an onBlur event only when the container div loses focus, instead the onBlur event is triggered everytime any element inside it loses focus

Comment: Please post the code relevant to your issue, and I'd be glad to assist.

Comment: Check this answer --> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092261/prevent-firing-the-blur-event-if-any-one-of-its-children-receives-focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092261/prevent-firing-the-blur-event-if-any-one-of-its-children-receives-focus)

Answer (score 4):

React [documents this problem](https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html#mouse-and-pointer-events) by utilizing the event loop with a `setTimeout` function with an empty second argument.