# How to prevent parent div lose focus when child element is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
<parent onBlur={function}>
  <child>
    <child>
    </child>
  </child>
</parent>
```

In a structure like this, I want to catch if parent element loses focus or not. I want to fire that behavior when clicked outside of the parent div. However, parent element loses its focus when I click child element as well. You can think this structure as dropdown menu. Is there a way to achieve this inside of the stateless react component? I cannot use jquery or other libraries.

Comment: perhaps [this article](https://medium.com/@jessebeach/dealing-with-focus-and-blur-in-a-composite-widget-in-react-90d3c3b49a9b) helps

Comment: or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092261/prevent-firing-the-blur-event-if-any-one-of-its-children-receives-focus)

Comment: React does not support focusin and focusout events thats the problem with this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092261/prevent-firing-the-blur-event-if-any-one-of-its-children-receives-focus]

Comment: divs do not have focus. tags like input do

Comment: @WaliWaqar where's the div?

Comment: @wolf - what about that article?

Comment: wolf calls it a "parent div" so i assumed that the react component returns a div

Comment: Yes it is true Wali, react component returns a div and it does have focus. Right now i am trying to implement something with react hooks. I will let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

**This can be achieved with mouse events.**

If the user clicks on the screen we can check if the click is inside or outside the component and treat it as Focus event to blur event.

- Click Inside - Focus
- Click Outside - Blur

```js
function Parent(props){
  const ref = useRef();
  
  useEffect(()=>{
  
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkFocus.bind(this))
    return ()=>{
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", checkFocus.bind(this))
    }
  },[])
  
  const checkFocus = (event)=>{
    if(ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target) && props.onBlur)
      props.onBlur()
  }
  
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
  
}

function Child(){

  return (
    <h1>child</h1>
  );

}

function Main(){

  return (
    <Parent onBlur={()=>{ console.log("focus lost.") }}>
      <Child>
        <Child>
        </Child>
      </Child>
    </Parent>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Parent component maintains a state isParentFocused to track whether the parent element is currently focused or not.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Parent = () => {
  const [isParentFocused, setIsParentFocused] = useState(false);

  const handleParentBlur = () => {
    // Using a timeout to check if the focus has moved to a child element
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!document.activeElement.closest('.parent')) {
        setIsParentFocused(false);
      }
    }, 0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="parent" onBlur={handleParentBlur} tabIndex="0">
      <Child />
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = () => {
  return (
    <div className="child">
      <div>Child Component</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

This way, clicking inside the child component will not trigger the blur event for the parent if the focus remains within the parent or its children.