# Event Listener Callback Fires Immediately When Set Inside The Callback of Another Event Listener. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

With a create-react-app boilerplate setup, I have an input field with an onFocus event passed. Within this onFocus callback I'm setting a click eventlistener on window.document.

When the input field is focused why does the clickHandler callback fire immediately?

```
function App() {

  const clickHandler = (e) => {
      console.log("clicked");
      window.document.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler)
  } 

  const focusHandler = (e) => {
      console.log('onFocus');
      e.stopPropagation()
      window.document.addEventListener("click", clickHandler)  
  }

  return (
   <div className="App">
          <input onFocus={focusHandler} />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: That is because of the time the events are triggered.`Focus` happens during the mouse down. And so ur function handler is called. `Click` happens on `mouseup`. Due to this, your click gets called because, by the time mouse up happens, your focus handler is called and `click` event is set.

Comment: I can't produce the problem you mention here. Also, you add the listener to `windows` instead of `window.document` in the `focusHandler` function. Probably a typo when you move the example here?

Comment: @devserkan yeah was a typo that I have now fixed

Comment: @Panther yes that's correct. Holding mouse down without releasing console.logs only the focus and when releasig logs the click. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the input, few events occur such as `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `focus` `click`. (fyi - click happens when a mousedown and mouseup event occur on the same element). In chrome, [focus handler is executed first and then the click handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282245/dom-event-precedence) is executed (if the handlers exist).

Now, in your code when you click on the input, `focusHandler` is executed where a click handler is attached to the `window`. By the time the js engine finishes the execution of `focusHandler`, there is a click handler registered already. So as soon as `focusHandler` is executed, the js engine realises that *'ah, there is a clickHandler that I need to execute it. Let me do it'* . Hence your clickHandler fires immediately.

You can test it by attaching event handler in a **setTimeout**. In below code, js engine has no clickHandler to execute after `focusHandler` execution is finished. So click handler won't fire immediately.

```js
const focusHandler = e => {
    console.log("onFocus");
    e.stopPropagation();
    setTimeout(() => window.addEventListener("click", clickHandler), 1000);
  };
```